# why "sess.graph.get_all_collection_keys()" return a empty collection?

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, feature-extraction

Sorry, I have searched all answers in "stackoverflow" but gained no satisfying result.
I am learning a inception v3 feature abstraction:
[codes on this site](https://github.com/piyo-papa/Feature_extraction_from_inception_v3)

when I insert a line:"print sess.graph.get_all_collection_keys()" to the code segmentation. The printed result is []. But using:"pool3 = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('pool_3:0')" has right result, Why?

***The code is:***

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

IMG_PATH = '/tmp/feature abstraction/panda.jpg'
MODEL_PATH = '/tmp/feature abstraction/classify_image_graph_def.pb'


inception_v3 = tf.gfile.FastGFile(MODEL_PATH, 'rb')
graph_def =tf.GraphDef()
graph_def.ParseFromString(inception_v3.read())
tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
layers_name=graph_def.ListFields()



with tf.Session() as sess:


#******

    print(sess.graph.get_all_collection_keys())
#*****



    pool3 = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('pool_3:0')
    #print sess.graph.get_all_collection_keys()
    print tf.get_default_graph().get_all_collection_keys()

    image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(IMG_PATH, 'rb').read()

    features = sess.run(pool3, {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})

#******
    print(sess.graph.get_all_collection_keys())
#*******


    print features.shape
    print(np.squeeze(features))
```

***The output is:***

```
[]

[]

[]

(1, 1, 1, 2048)

[ 0.21214311  0.04288583  0.14220749 ...,  0.09034956  0.0148661
  0.13966754]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to export/import your graph in a MetaGraphDef representation (see documentation on GraphDef and MetaGraphDef : https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/programmers_guide/graphs). The MetaGraphDef contains more information about your graph (such as the contents of the graph collections).

Comment: Very grateful! Maybe it is for this reason, I have tried in other ways, it done!